# What is the max for Network bytes In Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

[image]

I am using Google Cloud, I need to know what is max MB of Network bytes for incoming Bytes/sec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern is about inbound traffic, you have details [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#vm-inbound-bw)

The next [chapter is about the outbound traffic](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#outbound_bandwidth).

I think that you will find all your answer in them!

Answer (score 1):

The maximum network throughput for a Google Compute service is 2 Gbit per CPU core to a theoretical maximum of 16 Gbit for each virtual machine.

[5 steps to better GCP network performance](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/5-steps-to-better-gcp-network-performance?hl=ml)

It is rare to achieve these numbers with real-world applications. You can achieve this will some network speed tests.

[Calculating network throughput](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/network-throughput)

Answer (score 0):

> The maximum network throughput for a Google Compute service is 2 Gbit
>   per CPU core to a theoretical maximum of 16 Gbit for each virtual
>   machine.

A VM did indeed have a 2 Gbit/s times the number of vCPUs egress limit, up to a maximum of 16 Gbit/s.
However that has changed.  For VMs with at least 2 vCPUs, there is now a 10 Gbit/s minimum limit.  And if the VM is defined as Skylake or better, the upper limit is 32 Gbit/s rather than 16.  As always, these limits are "guaranteed not to exceed" rather than "guaranteed to achieve."

Comment: Since these answers, Google has released its "Advanced Networking" (aka TIER_1) options.  Depending on the VM machine type and vCPU count, one can get an egress cap of either 50, 75, or 100 Gbit/s.  Keep in mind that as always, egress caps are "Guaranteed not to exceed. Not guaranteed to achieve."